# Google Chrome extensions: popup windows handling

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension should open a popup window (a normal popup window, not default extensions popup) with a following conditions:

1. only one window could be opened in the moment,
2. I want to save window size and position in localStorage, and restore them on next open.

How to do so?

I tried:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {

  // 1. In this case, variable win is a window object. But it's empty. There
  // is no properties/methods to operate with.
  var win = window.open('http://example.com','windowname');

  chrome.windows.create({
    'url': 'http://example.com',
    'type': 'popup'
  }, function(win) {
    // 2. In this case, variable win has some properties, but they are static
    // and won't change on window resize/close.
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's special about the opened window? How does the extension know whether a "window" has been opened or not? If it's based on the URL, [here](https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications/blob/4f4aa9ce76bce8f9f8c4180a73c675b5d9651f86/using-websocket.js#L66-L82) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do this with `window.open()`.

**1-only one window could be opened in the moment,**

If you give same `name`, `window.open()`,

- if there aren't any exist windows with same name, It will create a new one
- else if there is a openned window with the same name, it will just refresh it.

**2- I want to save window size and position in localStorage, and restore them on next open.**

Yes, you can do this by attaching `window.onresize` event,

Here is a basic example,

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  var wOpt = getWindowDefaultOptions(); // options from localStorage
  var win = window.open("http://www.example.com", "myscriptpopup", "width="+wOpt.width+", height="+wOpt.height+", top="+wOpt.top+", left="+wOpt.left);
  win.onresize = function() {
      var newOptions = {};
      newOptions.width = this.innerWidth;
      newOptions.height = this.innerHeight;
      newOptions.top = this.screenY;
      newOptions.left = this.screenX;
      setWindowDefaultOptions(newOptions); //save Options to localStorage
  }
});

//Default Options For Window
var winOptions = {
      "width" : "200",
      "height" : "100",
      "top" : "50",
      "left" : "50"
};
```

Comment: For some reason `win.onresize()` is called only two times, on window open.